# Is there any way to use Twilio SDK without CallKit?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

With the latest iOS [PushKit Push Notification Policy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry), it is impossible to use PushKit without CallKit.
But Twilio iOS SDK is still using PushKit.
Is there any way to use the Twilio SDK without the default iOS CallKit screen?
Because I need to implement the custom call incoming screen.
I hope your help.

Kind Regards